# How to reuse process result of fixed data

Tags: ssas, olap

In a financial system, transactions of every year is stored in a separate table. So, there are Transactions2007, Transactions2008, ..., Transactions2012 tables in the system. They all have the same table design. The data in tables of previous years never change. But current years data is updated in a daily manner.
I want to build a cube on the union of tables of all years. The question is how to prevent SSAS from reprocessing previous years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled it by partitioning the cube (by time dimension) and processing only the most recent partition.

Answer (score 1):

When processing the Cube, you can set the cube process option to Process Incremental and then in the Configuration Dialog, you can select a query to select data only from the recent tables. Here is a [link](http://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/ssas-process-incremental/) for more info.